# How to combine font-awesome and CSS triangles?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, css-shapes

I'm trying to make a generic solution for adding triangles to font-awesome icons. I have a working demo of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/2gG6d/5/

But this is not very elegant and flexible, as the code contains both font sizes and margins in pixel values. It would be perfect if the size and placement of the triangle are generated based on the parent's font size, and of course also support font-awesome's "fa-2x"-"fa-5x" classes: http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="triangle"> 
   <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #68aaa9;
}
.triangle:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-color: #68aaa9;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -6px
}
```

Comment: CSS triangles are based on border-widths (as you know) but these can **only** be defined in PX based values (px, em, rem). Percentage based values do not work.

Comment: I think if the border-withs and margins were set in em it would give the desired behaviour (triangle size and placement according to parent font-size)

Comment: Maybe LESS mixins can be used to generate the desired values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your *CSS* in order to get to the desired behaviour. The triangles are sized and positioned according to the parents font size. This isn't pixel perfect but you should get the idea and be able to tweak it.

The point is to use only em or percent values to position the triangles and set the border-width.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2gG6d/67/)** (I also simplified the stylesheet so it is easier to tweak)

After this, you can add new classes with other values of border-width and positioning for the other classes you want to support (`fa-2x`-`fa-5x`).

*Relevant CSS :*

```
.triangle {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #68aaa9;
    line-height:1em;
}
.triangle:after {
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 0.18em solid transparent;
}
.triangle.triangle-bottom:after {
    top: 90%;
    right:0.268em;
    border-top-color: currentColor;
}
.triangle.triangle-top:after {
    bottom: 0.95em;
    left:0.268em;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
}
.triangle.triangle-left:after {
    right: 100%;
    top: 0.268em;
    border-right-color: currentColor;
}
.triangle.triangle-right:after {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0.268em;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can change the border-color declarations from `#68aaa9` to  **`currentColor`** and it automatically reacts to the color of the font.

Comment: @Paulie_D that is awesome, didn't know about it.

Comment: Cool! Never used currentColor before. Seems to be ok supported as well: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/currentColor